# Parse Complex Xml in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to show data before parsing Local XML but don't know how?I
 tried it by using this

```
 XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("Record.xml"); var data = from
 query in loadedData.Descendants("item")
        select new Person {
          Name = (string)query.Element("record"),
        }; listBox1.ItemsSource = data;
```

but it shows me only one element and not show Title Name.

XML is:

```
 <root>
 <item name="Title 1">
   <record>record1</record>
   <record>record2</record>
</item>
   <item name="Title 2">
   <record>record1</record>
   <record>record2</record>
</item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code:

```
            XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("Try.xml");
            var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("item")
                       from a in query.Elements("record")
                       select new Person
            {
                Name = (string)a.Value

            };
            var array = data.ToArray();
```